# Inner product over finite fields

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inner-products, information-theory, combinatorial-geometry

EDIT: I moved this question to overflow forum, wasn't aware of the difference, sorry.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252396/inner-product-over-finite-fields

---

Let $F$ be a finite field,

For every $c \in F$, let $X_1, X_2,..., X_9, Y_1,..., Y_9$ be independent non-zero random variables over $F$.

Denote $X=(X_1,...,X_9)$, $Y=(Y_1,...,Y_9)$, also let $<X,Y>=\sum_{i}X_i Y_i$.

---

**Question**: show that
$\sum_{x,y: <x,y>=c} (P( (X,Y)=(x,y) ))^{17/18} \leq 1$.

---

Remarks:

-feel free to swap $17/18$ for any other constant smaller then 1.

-I can prove this for flat distributions

-I can prove it for dimension 2, that is for $X_1, S_1$ instead of 18 random variables.

I'd be super grateful for the proof or sketch or idea that actually works :-).

Best regards,

Maciej

Comment: How are the random variables related to the finite field?  What does the superscript ($17/18$, or anything else positive and $< 1$) in the probability notation mean?

Comment: They are all random variables over $F$, as for superscript- it's exponent. I'll edit it to make it more clear, sorry.

Comment: For this not to be true we would need $P(\left\langle X,Y\right\rangle=c)$ to be as large as $\left|F\right|^{-0.53}$. I suspect that when $c\neq 0$ this is quite hard to arrange because of the independence of the random variables. (When you say $X_1,\dots,Y_9$ are "non-zero", do you mean "never zero" or "not always zero"?).

Comment: I mean "never zero", but we're quite flexible with it, you can exclude any other value(s). I think zero should play crucial role here